# Angular popover binding doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to bind popover content value. I'm using ng-bootstrap.

The input that listen on text change :

```
<input (keyup)="onTextChange($event)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter font family">
```

My popover button :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" placement="top"
    [ngbPopover]="text2" popoverTitle="Popover on top"> Popover on top </button>
```

The ts file :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-popover-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/popover-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdPopoverBasic {
  text2: string = '';

  onTextChange(event: any) {
    this.text2 = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

It works but not as expected. The popover content value doesn't change when the popover is active, I have to close and re open it to see that the popover value has changed.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do : http://plnkr.co/edit/WS65zQNNvO99YwXmafFE?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, `@ngbPopover` only updates after the `open` method is called.

You can modify your code like this. The idea is that you must close popover before set value and then reopen.

**HTML**

```
<input (keyup)="onTextChange($event)" type="text" class="form-control" id="fontFamilyHeader" aria-describedby="fontFamilyHeader" placeholder="Enter font family">

<button class="btn btn-primary" ngbPopover #a="ngbPopover">Click me </button>
```

**ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-popover-triggers',
  templateUrl: 'src/popover-triggers.html'  
})
export class NgbdPopoverTriggers {
  @ViewChild('a') public a:NgbPopover;

  public onTextChange(event: any) {


    const isOpen = this.a.isOpen();
    if(isOpen)
    {
       this.a.close();
    }
    this.a.ngbPopover= event.target.value;
    this.a.open(event.target.value);

  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you